# How to check if the elements of a range exist in a list?

Tags: prolog

It is the first time that he has programmed with the Prolog language, and he wanted to know how I can start from a list and two numbers Min and Max, to see if the numbers between Min and Max exist in the list.

Example: existerango([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],5,9) should return true, because in the list there is 5,6,7,8, there is the entire range between 5 and 9 (not counting the last one).

I was thinking something like this:

```
existerango([],Min,Max).
existerango(L,X,Y) :- existerango2(L,X,Y,N).
```

And what I want it to show:

```
existerango([1,3,7,8,2],1,4).  
true.

existerango([1,3,7,8,2],X,Y).
X = 1 , Y = 2.
X = 1 , Y = 4.
...
```

all posibilities.

So with this second function "existerango2" add the variable N in order to see if the following condition is verified: N = Y-X, since if this is true all the elements of the range exist, obviously I will increase N each time It is fulfilled that the element of the list is between the two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
existorango(List, Max, Max) :-
    memberchk(Max, List).

existorango(List, Min, Max) :-
    memberchk(Min, List),
    succ(Min, Next),
    existorango(List, Next, Max).
```

e.g.

```
?- trace, existorango([1,2,3,4,5], 2, 4).   %<-- query
 Call:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],2,4)
 Call:memberchk(2,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])          % check if 2 is in 1,2,3,4,5
 Exit:memberchk(2,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 Call:succ(2,_772)                          % successor after 2 is ?
 Exit:succ(2,3)                             % it's 3
 Call:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],3,4)      % call Min=3, Max=4
 Call:memberchk(3,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])          % check if 3 is in 1,2,3,4,5
 Exit:memberchk(3,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 Call:succ(3,_774)                          % Next after 3 is ?
 Exit:succ(3,4)                             % it's 4
 Call:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],4,4)      % call Min=4, Max=4 (same!)
 Call:memberchk(4,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])          % check if 4 is in List
 Exit:memberchk(4,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 Exit:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],4,4)      % no more calls, exit out
 Exit:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],3,4)
 Exit:existorango([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],2,4)
true                                        % yep, all checked
```

Count from the `Min` upwards checking if each `Next` is a member of the list. When the Next number and Max are the same, check if that's in the list, and stop.

or, shorter:

```
existerango(List, Min, Max) :-
    forall(between(Min, Max, Number), memberchk(Number, List)).
```

"For all the Numbers between Min and Max, check that they are a member of the List".